Running a Breadth-First Search in Sql-G to get both vertices and edges
I am working on SqlG (https://sqlg.org/docs/3.1.0/) which is an extension of Apache TinkerPop for PostgreSql. I want to perform a breadth-first search from an initial vertex and get all the vertices along with the edges.
I am running the following code where I am getting only the vertices and no edge information. How can I get the edge information?
My usecase is to display a graph whenever a vertex is provided but that will be of less importance if I do not have the edge information.
Map<String, String> conf = new HashMap<>();
conf.put("jdbc.url", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/marko");
conf.put("jdbc.username", "postgres");
conf.put("jdbc.password", "postgres");
Configuration configuration = new MapConfiguration(conf);
Graph graph = SqlgGraph.open(configuration);

//Creating a usual TinkerPop example Graph
graph.traversal().tx().open();
Vertex personMarko = graph.addVertex(T.label, "person", "name", "marko", "age", 29);
Vertex personJosh = graph.addVertex(T.label, "person", "name", "josh", "age", 32);
Vertex personVadas = graph.addVertex(T.label, "person", "name", "vadas", "age", 27);
Vertex personPeter = graph.addVertex(T.label, "person", "name", "peter", "age", 35);
Vertex softwareRipple = graph.addVertex(T.label, "software", "name", "ripple", "lang", "java");
Vertex softwareLop = graph.addVertex(T.label, "software", "name", "lop", "lang", "java");

personMarko.addEdge("knows", personJosh, "weight", 1.0);
personMarko.addEdge("knows", personVadas, "weight", 0.5);

personMarko.addEdge("created", softwareLop, "weight", 0.4);
personJosh.addEdge("created", softwareLop, "weight", 0.4);
personPeter.addEdge("created", softwareLop, "weight", 0.2);
personJosh.addEdge("created", softwareRipple, "weight", 1.0);
graph.tx().commit();

My ACTUAL Code for traversal:
Vertex start = graph.traversal().V().hasLabel("person").has("name", "marko").next();
graph.traversal().V(start).repeat(__.outE().inV()).emit().path().forEachRemaining(path -> {
    System.out.println("PATH DETAILS");
    for(Object object : path) {
        if(object instanceof Vertex) {
            Vertex vertex = (Vertex) object;
            String name = vertex.value("name") + "";
            String label = vertex.label();
            System.out.print(String.format("%s[%s] ", name, label));
        }
        if(object instanceof Edge) {
            //This block is never executed!!!
            System.out.println("EDGE FOUND");
            Edge edge = (Edge) object;
            String label = edge.label();
            System.out.print(String.format("%s ", label));
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
});


That's a strange one.  If you change the instanceof Edge to instanceof Element does it still not return anything related to the edges?
